# Excel add-in on startup

Tags: c#, excel, office-addins

I am creating an add in for Microsoft Excel using Visual C#.  When I first created the solution, it included a function called ThisAddIn_Startup.  I added the following code to this function:

```
private void ThisAddIn_Startup(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
{
    MessageBox.Show("Startup");
}
```

The message box does not show upon installing the add in and starting Microsoft Excel.  Indeed, NOTHING in this function works when the add in loads.  This is literally the only change I've made to this new project after first creating it.  Why won't it work?

Comment: Are you certain the addin is installed correctly and enabled in Excel?

Comment: I can add a ribbon tab, buttons, functions, and even forms, and they all work just fine.  For some reason, this one function refuses to work.  I cannot do even the simplest thing when the program starts up.

Comment: Deleted my answer, as there is obviously more to it than the basics, but sadly it "works on my machine" so I can't reproduce the problem and help you. Can only suggest you try on another machine if you are able

Answer (score 0):

Nothing is magic and `ThisAddIn_Startup` is called by something before executing your `MessageBox.Show` instruction.

You can use "Find All References" in Visual Studio, it will bring you to `ThisAddin.InternalStartup()`, a private method in `ThisAddin.cs`.

This method is called by the framework's runtime.

Did this explanation help?

Answer (score 0):

When developing AddIn's for Excel you will sometimes create bugs that will trigger Excel to disable the AddIn.  If so you need to Go into Excel, go to File / Options and select Add-Ins.  At the lower left of the screen there is a drop down list with the label "Manage:".  Select "Disabled Items" and click Go button.  If your tool is disabled you will see it there and you can re-enable it.  This was an example from Office 2010.  The new version might have rearranged this, I don't know.